# Disabled 802.11n is stable but slow, enabled is fast but unstable

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.04, iwlwifi

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04. After reading up that support for KabyLake CPUs is actually on 17.04, I completely wiped my harddrive and switched to 17.04.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series, with Intel Wireless 3165.

When I was on windows 10, the WiFi worked perfectly at full speed with no disconnectss, but since switching to Ubuntu, I have suffered very slow wifi connection. I googled and found various proposed solutions, like putting IPv6 on ignore, disabling / enabling 802.11n.

Nothing I tried worked or had any effect whatsoever, except changing the 802.11n value in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Currently this file has `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`, but testing speed with https://fast.com/ gives me about 2-4 Mbps. Changing the value to 8 causes my WiFi to work at full speed (60-80 Mbps on https://fast.com/), but after a short period of inactivity it stops working (no disconnect, but pinging 8.8.8.8 can't resolve host and webpages don't load), but after about a minute of trying, it seems to start working again at full speed.

**debugging wifi info [if anything is missing please let me know]**

`sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 79
       serial: 70:1c:e7:e2:80:0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=20.0.0.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:291 memory:d1000000-d1001fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: br-2e55f403ebd6
       serial: 02:42:45:45:7d:eb
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.19.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: br-a78071d77c33
       serial: 02:42:1a:5c:4b:f6
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:16:38:8a:cc
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

`iwconfig`

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"OL5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  
          Bit Rate=433.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:86   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: DSL or cable? WPA2-AES? 2.4ghz or 5ghz? Channel number?

Comment: DSL, WPA/WPA2 Personal (not sure about AES), 5ghz. I don't know what channel number means. I'd like to note that everyone else in the office has perfect connection with win10. I am the only one with ubuntu, and the only one experiencing these issues, so I'm assuming that the problem is on my end

Comment: What is your MTU? Do you have any control/access to the router?

Comment: My MTU is set to automatic, I have access to the router

Comment: Give me a minute to put together a quick possible solution... in the mean time, set your /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf back to default.

Comment: Please update me with your status. Did the MTU setting help?

Comment: I left work shortly after you posted your answer. I assure you, this will be the first thing I try when I get there. I will keep you posted (and not just because I've been suffering this for well over a week now)

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: Set your `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` back to original.

**Note**: Check that encryption is set to WPA2-**AES** (not WPA/WPA2 and not TKIP) in your router.

Your problem may be with the MTU setting for your DSL connection.

There's a MTU setting in Ubuntu's network configuration, and a WAN MTU setting in your router.

For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first in your wireless network profile in Ubuntu.

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In terminal:

```
ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]
```

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

```
ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8 # this will probably show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8 # may show fragmentation

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8 # no fragmentation?

ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8 # still no fragmentation?
```

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: I hope I did this right. I switched MTU on my wireless connection options to 1492. I tried `ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8` got "message too long". I tried again with 1462, and got response. I kept increasing by 1 until I reached 1464 which worked, but adding 28 to that gets me back to 1492. Speed still completely stops on slight inactivity. I should point out that if I keep a terminal active with `ping 8.8.8.8` it never drops.

Comment: I made a backup of the original `iwlwifi.conf` and got it back, it contains: `remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211`

Comment: Show me `iwconfig`. I want to see if power management is off.

Comment: edited into question for better formating

Comment: Power management looks ok, it's off. Did you check that your router is set for WPA2-AES on both bands, yes? Lets try connecting to a channel on the 2.4ghz band and see if it's more stable there.

Comment: I looked everywhere in the router config page, saw nothing about AES, just WPA2/Personal (not allowed to change that). I connected to our 2.4ghz band, and I will let you know if it's stable or not, though fast.com gives 30mbps. I also ran into the link you provided when I searched for the solution to this problem, and replaced the ucode files, they had no effect.

Comment: For AES, it would probably be on the same tab where you found WPA2, but it could also be in the security tab. Let me know if 2.4ghz is more stable.

Comment: 2.4ghz is unstable as well. I get the feeling the the issue is with my drivers. When my speed dropped to 0 last time, I tried switching back to the 5ghz band, it took over a minute to connect, just like it takes about a minute from inactivity to full speed.

Comment: Maybe you're correct. Somewhere I saw that somebody had made updates to the iwlwifi driver... but I can't remember where I saw it... maybe it was on github or sourceforge. The driver was called iwlwifi_new, or something like that. I'll see if I can't find it again.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. You were very patient, helpful, and nice, but sadly I reached a point where I can't sacrifice my productivity at work trying to solve this, and have been asked to wipe Ubuntu and switch to Windows10. Again, thank you for trying.